# auctex+reftex doesn't insert labels for tcbcolorbox environments

Tags: tcolorbox, auctex, reftex

Until yesterday, it was all well, but today `auctex+reftex` doesn't insert automatically the keyval style labels.

I have, as part of `custom-set-variables`

```
'(reftex-label-alist
   '(
     (nil 97 nil "~\\cref{%s}" nil nil)
     ("bigthm" ?b "bigthm:" "~\\cref{%s}" nil nil)
     ("conj" ?c "conj:" "~\\cref{%s}" nil nil)
     ("cor" ?C "cor:" "~\\cref{%s}" nil nil)
     ("defn" ?d "defn:" "~\\cref{%s}" nil nil)
     ("lem" ?l "lem:" "~\\cref{%s}" nil nil)
     ("problem" ?p "problem:" "~\\cref{%s}" nil nil)
     ("prop" ?P "prop:" "~\\cref{%s}" nil nil)
     ("quest" ?q "quest:" "~\\cref{%s}" nil nil)
     ("rem" ?r "rem:" "~\\cref{%s}" nil nil)
     ("thm" ?T "thm:" "~\\cref{%s}" nil nil)
     )
   t)
```

The definitions of the theorem-like environments are in a latex style file called `matyi.sty`and I have a corresponding `matyi.el` in `~/.emacs.d/site-lisp`

When I enter `C-c C-e` the `defn` environment ends up looking like

```
\begin{defn}{Average}{}
  
\end{defn}
```

while I expected something like

```
\begin{defn}[label={defn:1}]{Average}{}
  
\end{defn}
```

I have

```
$ rpm -q emacs emacs-auctex
emacs-28.1-2.fc36.x86_64
emacs-auctex-13.1-1.fc36.noarch
```

on my Fedora Linux 36 system.

I also have

```
$ cat ~/.emacs.d/site-lisp/matyi.el
(TeX-add-style-hook
     "matyi"
     (lambda ()
       (TeX-run-style-hooks "tcolorbox" "tcolorboxlib-theorems" "cleveref")
       (LaTeX-add-tcolorbox-lib-theorems-newtcbtheorems
        '("defn" "defn")
        '("thm" "thm")
    '("problem" "problem")
    '("prop" "prop")
    '("lem" "lem")
    '("quest" "quest")
    '("cor" "cor")
    '("conj" "conj")
    '("rem" "rem")
    ))
     :latex)
```

and

```
TeX-style-private is a variable defined in ‘tex.el’.

Its value is ("/home/apu/.emacs.d/site-lisp/")
Original value was 
("/home/apu/.emacs.d/auctex/style")

TeX-auto-local is a variable defined in ‘tex.el’.

Its value is "auto"
```

Comment: Can you add the content of your `matyi.el` to your question?  And what's the value of the variable `TeX-style-private`?  `matyi.el` should actually reside in a directory in that variable.  And what's the value of `TeX-auto-local`?

Comment: I added what you requested.

Comment: Thanks, one last thing: You don't have AUCTeX also installed from ELPA by chance and have updated it shortly?

Comment: No, I don't but I'll do that and will report back.

Comment: I installed latest auctex via elpa, but I still see the error. I try to come up with a minimal working example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AUCTeX support file `tcolorboxlib-theorems.el` is now officially part of AUCTeX distribution, but the file has changed a little since its first incarnation.  I think the easiest solution is that you adjust your `matyi.el` to `tcolorboxlib-theorems.el` which is actually just touching the arguments of the function `LaTeX-add-tcolorbox-lib-theorems-newtcbtheorems`.  The new version can look like this:

```lisp
(TeX-add-style-hook
 "matyi"
 (lambda ()
   ;; Run only the style hook for 'tcolorbox'
   (TeX-run-style-hooks "tcolorbox" "cleveref")

   ;; This is the library we want to use:
   (LaTeX-add-tcolorbox-tcbuselibraries
    "theorems")

   ;; Now load the library with the provided function:
   (LaTeX-tcolorbox-load-used-libraries)

   ;; These are the additional environments defined in 'matyi.sty':
   (LaTeX-add-tcolorbox-lib-theorems-newtcbtheorems
    "conj"
    "cor"
    "defn"
    "lem"
    "problem"
    "prop"
    "quest"
    "rem"
    "thm")

   ;; Add the envs to `LaTeX-label-alist':
   (let ((envs '(("conj" . "conj:")
                 ("cor" . "cor:")
                 ("defn" . "defn:")
                 ("lem" . "lem:")
                 ("problem" . "problem:")
                 ("prop" . "prop:")
                 ("quest" . "quest:")
                 ("rem" . "rem:")
                 ("thm" . "thm:"))))
     (dolist (env envs)
       (add-to-list 'LaTeX-label-alist env t)))

   ;; Also make them available to RefTeX:
   (when (fboundp 'reftex-add-label-environments)
     (reftex-add-label-environments
      '(("conj" ?c "conj:" "~\\cref{%s}"
         LaTeX-tcolorbox-lib-theorems-reftex-label-context-function
         nil)
        ("cor" ?C "cor:" "~\\cref{%s}"
         LaTeX-tcolorbox-lib-theorems-reftex-label-context-function
         nil)
        ("defn" ?d "defn:" "~\\cref{%s}"
         LaTeX-tcolorbox-lib-theorems-reftex-label-context-function
         (regexp "[Dd]efinitions?") nil)
        ("lem" ?l "lem:" "~\\cref{%s}"
         LaTeX-tcolorbox-lib-theorems-reftex-label-context-function
         (regexp "[Ll]emmas?") nil)
        ("problem" ?p "problem:" "~\\cref{%s}"
         LaTeX-tcolorbox-lib-theorems-reftex-label-context-function
         (regexp "[Pp]roblems?") nil)
        ("prop" ?P "prop:" "~\\cref{%s}"
         LaTeX-tcolorbox-lib-theorems-reftex-label-context-function
         nil)
        ("quest" ?q "quest:" "~\\cref{%s}"
         LaTeX-tcolorbox-lib-theorems-reftex-label-context-function
         nil)
        ("rem" ?r "rem:" "~\\cref{%s}"
         LaTeX-tcolorbox-lib-theorems-reftex-label-context-function
         nil)
        ("thm" ?T "thm:" "~\\cref{%s}"
         LaTeX-tcolorbox-lib-theorems-reftex-label-context-function
         (regexp "[Tt]heorems?") nil)))) )
 :latex)
```

You can also reset your additions to `reftex-label-alist` which are now done when `matyi.el` is loaded.